# Unable to find type [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm trying to queue a build from Powershell specifying Process Parameters.  I'm getting the following error ... any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Unable to find type `[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]`: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

`At line:19 char:1`
+ $paramValues = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::Deseri ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:  (Microsoft.TeamF...WorkflowHelpers:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound`

```
    function Get-BuildServer
        {
        param($serverName = $(throw 'please specify a TFS server name'))
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client")
        $tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($serverName)

        return $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
        }

    # SAS: Get the Build Server
    $buildserver = Get-BuildServer "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/My%20Project%20Collection"

    # SAS: Set the parameters (Team Project and Build Definition)
    $teamProject = "MyProject"
    $buildDefinition = "MyBuildDefinition"

    # SAS: Get the build definition
    $definition = $buildserver.GetBuildDefinition($teamProject, $buildDefinition)

    # SAS: Create the build request
    $request = $definition.CreateBuildRequest()

    # SAS: Deserialise the Process Parameter for the Build Definition
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow")
    $paramValues = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::DeserializeProcessParameters($request.ProcessParameters)

    # SAS: Set the parameter(s)
    $paramValues.Item("asdf") = "new value"

    # SAS: Serialise the Process Parameter for the Build Definition
    $request.ProcessParameters = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::SerializeProcessParameters($paramValues)

    # SAS: Queue the build
    $buildserver.QueueBuild($request, "None")
```

Comment: Simple ... not in the GAC! Grrr!  Thanks anyway ... but it's solved :-)

Comment: on a new Windows 10 machine with VS2015 and TFS power tools for 2015 with Powershell I was surprised to find the dlls are no longer under the Program Files (x86)\ Visual studio version but instead must be referenced from  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools" which resolved the same error for me.

Answer (score 1):

not in the GAC! You need to add dll to GAC
or
try this

```
add-type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll'
```