# Queuing TFS Build from Powershell Script Which is Called from TFS Build

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have a build definition that I use where when I kick it off, it calls a Powershell Script which actually queues multiple builds. The code I use came from this web page as reference: [How to queue build from powershell script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2007/04/25/queuing-a-build-in-powershell.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)

This script runs fine and works if I call it from the ISE or from the Powershell console. But if I call it from the build, it doesn't work. Any ideas why this may happen?

Comment: That code is really old, the API have changed, so you should specify: a) which TFS version you are using and b) show your code

Comment: 1) I believe I'm running TFS 2013 update 2
2) I'm running the exact code from the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use tfsbuild.exe command line utility. Open a "Developer Command Prompt" and type `TFSBuild help start`.

You can also use a script using the right APIs (e.g. [How to queue another TFS (2012) Build from a TFS Build AND pass process parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947772/how-to-queue-another-tfs-2012-build-from-a-tfs-build-and-pass-process-paramete)).

Third option is to customized the build template with the [Community Build Extensions](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/).

Comment: what I was doing was correct, but because I removed getting files from TFS and a bunch of other stuff from my build process, It couldn't queue because it didn't know what was what. Thanks for the help