# Queuing a build using Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, scripting

I want to use a powershell script to queue a TFS build( prompting the user to enter the custom build defination) and wait until the build completes and check the status of  that build and do a copy if it succeeds or exit if it fails. I would like to thank you in advance for taking time to answer my question

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use **tfsbuild.exe** command. This tool is located in Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio xx\Common7\IDE. More detail info to use start command: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181742(v=vs.100).aspx

You can also use a script using the APIs, [How to queue another TFS (2012) Build from a TFS Build AND pass process parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947772/how-to-queue-another-tfs-2012-build-from-a-tfs-build-and-pass-process-paramete)

Which things your want to copy? In the build definition, you can specify a drop folder to copy your build outputs in it.